# Static uniform background image in UISlider?

Tags: ios, background-image, uislider

Is there any way to set a static uniform background image on a UISlider?
I want to select a color hue with it and it would be great to have the hue range as a background image that stays the same no matter where the thumb is located. I can't think of a way to do this with setMinimumTrackImage and setMaximumTrackImage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't achieve the effect you want using the track images. I had the same need in one of my apps. What I did was display the hue range image just under the slider. I also used a custom thumb image that had more of a point on the bottom so it was clear which hue value was being selected by the slider.